# error handling while edittext empty data

Tags: java, android, xml

I just want asking about code that for edittext in android apps. if my edittext in layout empty, when user click the button for next section, will have a pop-up or dialog box appears that alerts user need to fill the edittext. its kind a error handling for my edittext. i'm just need a sample code that useful for me to understand. but in my needed, it have more than one edittext that user need to fill. so, all the edittext wil empty its will appear a dialog box and alerts that need user fill edittext. need for expertise help for show or give a sample code for me...

Comment: Please post what you have tried since this is a very nice learning oppurtunity. Asking people to write your code for you defeats the point of learning how to code for a platform. [This](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) will help get your feeling for Android.

Comment: @user1906140 Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
               EditText firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
               String name = firstname.getText.toString();

               if(name.length()<0){
               //your error alertbox;
               }
```

I'll give you a starting point to work on. This is part of the things you need. The above code will check whether your editext box is empty or not. What you need to do is look into alertbox. Post whatever you tried and your findings. If you got anything that you don't understand, feel free to post here and ask.

This is an example of creating alert box.

http://android-developing.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-create-alert-boxes.html

Answer (score -1):

Please Use below code for compare edittext value, it will solve your problem.

For One Edittext:-

```
EditText mEdttxt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);

if(mEdttxt1.getText().toString().equals("") || mEdttxt1.getText().toString().equals(" ")){
    mError="Please Enter First Name";
    mErrorAlertDialog();
} 

public void mErrorAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
    mAlertDialog.setTitle("Dipak Keshariya");

    mAlertDialog.setMessage(mError);
    mAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    mAlertDialog.show();
}
```

For All Edittext pass one by one value instead of mEdttxt1 and try it will solve your problem.